# Why does Python's max() function place a low value on strings with a leading space?

Tags: python, python-2.7, cpython

### The Quesion

I've noticed that the built-in `max()` function in Python 2.7.6 seems to place a low "value" on strings with a leading space unless I specifically tell it to use the `len` function as the key. Why is that?

### Example

Consider this snippet from the interactive interpreter:

> >>> max(['abc', 'defgh'])
>   'defgh'
>   >>> max(['abc', ' defgh'])
>   'abc'
>   >>> max([' defgh'])
>   ' defgh'
>   >>> max(['abc', ' defgh'], key=len)
>   ' defgh'

### Notes

I tried looking at [the source](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/c6880edaf6f3/Python/bltinmodule.c#l1438) for `max()`, and it calls [min_max()](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/c6880edaf6f3/Python/bltinmodule.c#l1335). On [line 1370](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/c6880edaf6f3/Python/bltinmodule.c#l1370), the case where no key is specified is handled. There is a comment that says "no key function; the value is the item". I don't know what value could be associated with a string besides length, so what does this comment mean? Also, why would a leading space affect the magical value that this C code is keying off of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python doesn't "ignore" the string at all - the behavior is precisely because Python *isn't* ignoring anything.

Rather a space *comes before* letters and strings are ordered lexicographical (case-sensitively!) or character-by-character. See an [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/) for the relative ordering of a space (Space=32) and other characters in the English alphabet ("a"=97).

That is, `" foo" < "foo"` is true, `min(" foo", "foo")` is `" foo"` and, conversely, `max(" foo", "foo")` is `"foo"`. Consequently, this also leads to `"Z" < "a"` being true which may be surprising..

If the code *wanted* to ignore the space then `max(.., key = lambda i: i.strip())` could be used, perhaps also with case-normalization thrown in as appropriate.

(The results from adding the key length function are irrelevant in this case, as larger length is max'er.)

Comment: *Duh, of course it's alphabetical order*... That was quite the time consuming brain fart for me. I'll accept this as soon as I can.

Answer (score 2):

Max is not using length, it's using alphabetical order:

```
>>> max(['abc', 'de'])
'de'
```

Space comes before 'a':

```
>>> ' ' < 'a'
True
```